# color the statusbar in android splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I added a splash screen to my android app and I'd like to give the status bar a color when showing.

This is the content of the file under drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_home"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and I added this style:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Adding the `colorPrimaryDark` item to your theme should do the trick:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You need to mention that this should be done in the `res\values-v21\styles.xml` if you have 2 `styles.xml` where the other `res\values\styles.xml` is for older android versions.

Comment: You may set it in the `res\values\styles.xml` as `colorPrimaryDark` will be ignored on older devices. For simple theme as a splash screen theme I prefer to keep it simple.

Comment: You can also add  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> so if the user minimises the app you would show your prefered color for app header.

Answer (score 1):

Insert  into **themes.xml** & **temes.xml(night):**

```
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/black</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
  getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add colorPrimaryDark item in your current splash theme in styles.xml :

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusbar_bg</item>
</style>
```

If you chose a light color for the status bar, you can add :

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

In colors.xml inside ressources add :

```
<color name="statusbar_bg">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Then use it as a second parameter while showing SplashScreen in MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```